# compact offset pointer , existing implementations?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, stl

Is there template in stl,boost or other LGPL open-source toolkit which behaves exactly like this:-
- a relative pointer with custom alignment,option to store fewer bits to reduce range.
a possible implementation to illustrate:-

```
template<typename T, typename OFFSET=int, 
    int ALIGN_SHIFT=2>
class   OffsetPtr 
{
    OFFSET  ofs;

public:
    T* operator->() {
        return  (T*) (((((size_t)this)>>ALIGN_SHIFT)+ofs)<<ALIGN_SHIFT);
    };
    void operator=(T* src) {
        size_t ofs_shifted = (((size_t) src)>>ALIGN_SHIFT) - (((size_t) this)>>ALIGN_SHIFT); //asserts..
        ofs = (OFFSET) (ofs_shifted);
    }
    //...
};
```

Its something I would routinely create in the past (compact cache-friendly precompiled data-structures), e.g. for data broken into sub 128k chunks OFFSET=short
Another variation I'd use in ancient C #defines would use offsets from a header, where the alignments would be more useful.

I've seen something about an 'interprocess library' in boost having an 'offset_ptr', that looks very similar, so it seems likely there's an existing implementation including this exact pattern *somewhere*.
It's quick to write but there might be benefits to an existing implementation like a suite of associated stl compliant data structures built around the same concept - a 'near vector' with 16bit offset pointer & 16bit count for example

Comment: Boost's `offset_ptr<>` is different than you want -- it stores the distance between the address of the offset pointer itself and the address of the pointed object, rather than allowing an arbitrary offset. Personally, I think it's poorly named; `relative_ptr<>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sure, as in 'relative addressing'. I'd usually called it offset so I was ok with that too - although perhaps I could call mine 'relative' to distinguish it from boosts', good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Visual C++, you might like to use [`__based` pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a97k4e.aspx).

Comment: thanks. I didn't know that existed. Sadly I must avoid MS specific extensions as I compile with gcc and llvm mostly, I wonder if c++11 has anything similar. Coming from low level code back in the days of asm , my usual method was an offset from the structure base itself which was usually most convenient. It also worked well as a C macro, but the above implementation was very tempting in C++.